# How do I extract a value from a set of labels in prometheus?

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I'm trying to create a grafana variable from a prometheus data source. I'll keep this short and to the point:
I have a set of values in the form:

`kube_namespace_labels{container="kube-state-metrics", endpoint="http", instance="10.208.108.149:8080", job="kube-state-metrics", namespace="stg", pod="prometheus-kube-state-metrics-7b86b6b968-mpqg7", service="prometheus-kube-state-metrics"}`

I need to get the value associated with `namespace` (so `namespace="stg"`).

How do I get this using PromQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
label_values(kube_namespace_labels,namespace)
```

See [Query variable](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/prometheus/#query-variable) and specifically:

`label_values(metric, label)`: Returns a list of label values for the `label` in the specified `metric`.

Comment: This has done the trick! I'm very new to prometheus and this has helped a huge bunch, thank you!

Comment: I'm pleased to hear it. You're welcome!